# DDS TIMFMT. Is it possible to get hh:mm?

Tags: ibm-midrange

I have a time input field in a display record, and I want it to be in the format hh:mm. The available formats either have seconds or AM/PM afterwards. The following is what I would like to do, but it doesn't work since the format doesn't exist.

```
A            SRTTIME         T  B  5 43TIMSEP(':') TIMFMT(*HM)
```

Is there an easy way to accomplish what I want without changing the field to a simple character field? I'm running on v7.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using a 4 digit numeric field with an EDTWRD. You might also consider EDTCDE(Y) DATSEP(':'). Or take a look at the "user-defined" edit codes on your system, named QEDIT5 - QEDIT9, with the DSPEDTD or WRKEDTD command. Or consider other keyboard shift codes in column 31.

```
....+....1....+....2....+....3....+....4....+....5....+....6....+....7....+....8
     A        TM1            4S 0B      3  4EDTWRD('0 :  ')
     A                                      EDTMSK('  &  ')
     A        TM2            4S 0B      4  4EDTCDE(Y) 
     A                                      DATSEP(':') 
     A
```

See the [DDS Reference](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzakc/displ.html)

Comment: Good suggestion to ask for input of 4 digits.  @Lundis will then have to create an actual time variable within his RPG program, probably setting the seconds to zero.